# iOS Notifications. Which one to use?

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

My calendar app is not connected to Event Kit which allows me to create custom repeating intervals like "every 3 days, 29 times" etc.

Now i would like to add Notifications to my Events ... but my custom repeating events are limiting me in every possible way.

I think I have checked every possible solution:

**UILocalNotification**
UILocalNotification is limited to 64 events and NSCalendarUnit's in-built Unit Time Intervals aren't very flexible.
1 event repeated every 2 days will fill this up very quickly
Should i reschedule 64 Notifications on every app start and beg the user to start the app regularly? Not running the app for a while will not reschedule notifications.

**Event Kit (Calendars & Reminders)**
I could create a calendar or Reminder list, generate single events from the custom repeating events and add notifications here. But the user can edit this, which will cause confusion.
I can't synch this back to my app.
Should i create a calendar or reminder list for Alerts and hope that the user will not touch this?

**Apple Push Notification Service**
Everywhere i can read: They are not reliable! There is no guarantee that push notifications will actually be delivered, even if the APNS server accepted them.
I think push notifications are not made for notifying the user at scheduled times as there is no guarantee they will arrive.

The question is what should i do, or what would you do in my case? No solution is perfect and i am hoping to find the most user friendly approach here. In case i am missing a approach, i would like to hear the alternative.

Edit:
Adding a another method for completeness.

**UILocalNotification without repeats**
don't offer the repeating of local notifications. The user can assign single Notifications to a event. After enabling the 65th notification, a popup will remind him that he has reached the system limit. This way you put the responsibility to the user. After reaching the limit he will be forced to focus on events that are not far in the future.

Comment: Could you use uiAlertView with timer for the notifications?

Comment: A UIAlertView will not be able to alert the user, when the app has entered background state or is being suspended.

Comment: As far as event kit limitation you have highlighted You could use the following snippet to observe the external changes to the calendar database [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(storeChanged:)name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification object:eventStore]; and sync back accordingly in your app.visit https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ObservingChanges/ObservingChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH4-SW1 to know more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to offer local notifications without repeat functionality.
This decision was made after chatting with a few users.
Better to offer something than to offer nothing :)

Comment: If you explain why eventkit was avoided it'd be helpful

Comment: Because the user can manipulate the calendar and i can't synch back.

Comment: See my comment to the question you could sync back using the code snippet I've mentioned.i have attached a link to verify my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could save all your events to core data and then every time the app is launched or when your main view appears load in all events for that week and set a scheduled local notification. Once the event is scheduled you set a flag in the entity eg hasBeenNotified.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My app uses core data. Loading the current week has two problems. 1.The user needs to open the app once a week minimum. 2.Opening it on the last day of the week would not schedule data for the next week. But probably this was only a example you used.